# Gnuplot array with character indices

Tags: arrays, character, gnuplot, indices

I would like to create an array in `gnuplot` with character indices. I have five data files named `a.txt`, `b.txt`, `c.txt` etc. Each text file has two columns of code profiling data (the function name and the CPU time in seconds):

```
# f         tcpu, s
function1   221.284
function2   161.412
function3   167.322
```

I would like to plot the *normalised* profiling data for all the files in a single histogram plot. Prior to normalising the data I have to find the maximum time value in each data file. I do this with `gnuplot` `stats` command in a `do for` loop. I would like to save the maxima in an array `tmax`. It would be convenient to use the character array indices (`tmax['a']`), but I cannot find a relevant example anywhere. Please find my minimal example below:

```
array tmax[5]

# detect and save maxima values
do for [l in "a b c d e"] {
    fname = sprintf('%s.txt', l)
    stats fname using 2
    tmax[l] = STATS_max
}

# print out maxima values
do for [l in "a b c d e"] {
    print l
    print tmax[l]
}
```

This attempt fails with the `array index out of range` error, when I try to save the `STATS_max` value in `tmax[l]`. If possible, could you please suggest, how to use character indices in a `gnuplot` array? The full `gnuplot` script follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot

set style data histogram
set style fill solid
set style histogram clustered
set xtics rotate by 45 offset 0,0 right
set lmargin  8
set bmargin 11

# border
set style line 11 lc rgb '#808080' lt 1
set border 3 back ls 11
set tics nomirror

# grid
set style line 12 lc rgb '#808080' lt 0 lw 1
set grid back ls 12

set terminal postscript eps size 3.5,2.62 enhanced color \
    font 'Helvetica, 10' linewidth 1

set output 'advisor.eps'
set xlabel 'C++ function'
set ylabel 't_{cpu} norm, %'

array tmax[5]

# detect and save maxima values
do for [l in "a b c d e"] {
    fname = sprintf('%s.txt', l)
    stats fname using 2
    tmax[l] = STATS_max
}

# print out maxima values
do for [l in "a b c d e"] {
    print l
    print tmax[l]
}

plot "a.txt" using ($2/tmax['a']):xtic(1) title 'p=1, t=1', \
     "b.txt" using ($2/tmax['b'])         title 'p=1, t=8', \
     "c.txt" using ($2/tmax['c'])         title 'p=8, t=1', \
     "d.txt" using ($2/tmax['d'])         title 'p=4, t=2', \
     "e.txt" using ($2/tmax['e'])         title 'p=2, t=4'
```

Example data file is:

```
# f                     tcpu, s
NUTS\\_prop             221.284
Grow\\_tree             161.412
Grow\\_branch           167.322
stan\\_gradient         160.204
log\\_prob\\_grad       160.034
leapfrog\\_integrator   128.392
log\\_prob              116.953
poisson\\_log\\_log     80.262
poisson\\_log\\_lpmf    80.252
add                     77.031
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be my suggestion. Instead of arrays, you can also store your data in strings and address the values via `real()` and `word()`, (check `help real` and `help word`). This will also work with older gnuplot 4.x versions.

Actually, I'm not sure whether I fully understood your normalization.
The example below divides the data of each file by the maximum time in that file. That's what I understood from your question.
Another option would be to compare the different settings (`p=1, t=1`, `p=1, t=8`, etc.) how long they take for a certain function (normalized to 1 for the longest time).

**Script:**

```
### loop several files for normalized histogram
reset session

myFiles   = "a b c d e"
myFile(n) = sprintf("%s.txt",word(myFiles,n))

# create some random test data
myFunctions = "f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6"
do for [i=1:words(myFiles)] {
    set print myFile(i)
        do for [j=1:words(myFunctions)] {
            print sprintf("%s %g", word(myFunctions,j),rand(0)*150+70)
        }
    set print
}

myTmaxs = ''
do for [i=1:words(myFiles)] {
    stats myFile(i) u 2 nooutput
    myTmaxs = myTmaxs.sprintf(" %g",STATS_max)
}
myTmax(n) = real(word(myTmaxs,n))
print myTmaxs

myTitles   = '"p=1, t=1" "p=1, t=8" "p=8, t=1" "p=4, t=2" "p=2, t=4"'
myTitle(n) = word(myTitles,n)

set style data histogram
set style fill solid 0.6
set style histogram clustered
set grid y
set key out
set yrange [0:]

plot for [i=1:words(myFiles)] myFile(i) u ($2/myTmax(i)):xtic(1) title myTitle(i)
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround would be to rename the data files into `1.txt`, `2.txt`, `3.txt` etc. Then the minimal example code will work with the following changes in syntax:

```
array tmax[5]

# detect and save maxima values
do for [l=1:5] {
    fname = sprintf('%d.txt', l)
    stats fname using 2
    tmax[l] = STATS_max
}

# print out maxima values
do for [l=1:5] {
    print l
    print tmax[l]
}
```